# Delete created uncommitted record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can not figure out how to delete a model created by `App.store.createRecord()`.
Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Adw4F/2/
You can delete record loaded from fixtures (or rest adapter), but not created.

Comment: Just a note, this issue has been fixed now.

Comment: Do you mean in the `relationship-improvements` branch?  It's not fixed in master.

Comment: Can't really say, I stopped using ember because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the very last version of ember-data, and adding a few *(ugly|crappy|clumsy)* things, I got it working. Obviously not ideal, but working...

See http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/Adw4F/32/

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't commit'ed the record, all you need to do is rollback the transaction.

Ember uses a default transaction if one wasn't specified. For example:

`record.get('transaction').rollback();`

This will transition the record to the deleted state.

Comment: Have you tried it?  What version of Ember does this work with?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
record.deleteRecord({})
```

Or roll the transaction back.